# How can I solve index out of range error on my Implementation based problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am practicing python 3 problems and I am stuck on one problem.

Little Petya very much likes gifts. Recently he has received a new laptop as a New Year gift from his mother. He immediately decided to give it to somebody else as what can be more pleasant than giving somebody gifts. And on this occasion he organized a New Year party at his place and invited n his friends there.

If there's one thing Petya likes more that receiving gifts, that's watching others giving gifts to somebody else. Thus, he safely hid the laptop until the next New Year and made up his mind to watch his friends exchanging gifts while he does not participate in the process. He numbered all his friends with integers from 1 to n. Petya remembered that a friend number i gave a gift to a friend number pi. He also remembered that each of his friends received exactly one gift.

Now Petya wants to know for each friend i the number of a friend who has given him a gift.

Input

The first line contains one integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100) — the quantity of friends Petya invited to the party.

The second line contains n space-separated integers: the i-th number is pi — the number of a friend who gave a gift to friend number i. It is guaranteed that each friend received exactly one gift. It is possible that some friends do not share Petya's ideas of giving gifts to somebody else. Those friends gave the gifts to themselves.

Output

Print n space-separated integers: the i-th number should equal the number of the friend who gave a gift to friend number i.

Code:

```
n=int(input())
gifts=input().split()
""" Reverse_gifts is just dummy list so that I can place each integer at 
its required place""" 
reverse_gifts=[range(n)]

""" For converting each item of gifts to integer"""
for num in range(len(gifts)):
    gifts[num]=int(gifts[num])

""" It will change the items of reverse_gifts to the items we need in 
output"""
for num1 in range(1,n+1):
    guest_recieved_gift=gifts.index(num1)
    reverse_gifts[num1-1]=guest_recieved_gift+1

print(reverse_gifts)

"""For converting each item of reverse gifts to string"""  
for num2 in range(len(gifts)):   
    reverse_gifts[num2]=str(reverse_gifts[num2])

""" For converting final list into string and print it"""
final_gifts=" ".join(reverse_gifts)
print(final_gifts)
```

Input:

```
4
2 3 4 1
```

Output: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "Presents.py", line 11, in <module>
reverse_gifts[num1-1]=guest_recieved_gift+1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: What is the index value at the point of failure?  What is the size of `reverse_gifts`?  You need to do some basic debugging.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `reverse_gifts=[range(n)]` which has a length 1 because currently it just contains a generator. Therefore, you end up with an `IndexError` because you are trying to access index greater than 0. You can unpack the values of the `range` generator to have a list with 4 elements using `*`

```
reverse_gifts=[*range(n)]
```

Alternative way is

```
reverse_gifts= list(range(n))
```

**Complete answer**

```
n=4
gifts="2 3 4 1".split()
reverse_gifts=[*range(n)]

for num in range(len(gifts)):
    gifts[num]=int(gifts[num])

for num1 in range(1,n+1):
    guest_recieved_gift=gifts.index(num1)
    reverse_gifts[num1-1]=guest_recieved_gift+1
print(reverse_gifts)
# [4, 1, 2, 3]

for num2 in range(len(gifts)):
    reverse_gifts[num2]=str(reverse_gifts[num2])
final_gifts=" ".join(reverse_gifts)

print(final_gifts)
# 4 1 2 3
```

Comment: yes, it worked. I was trying to find error from 1 hour. It has been just 15 days that I started python and I was not knowing about the thing which you told me. Thanks

Comment: Again thanks for giving me info about accepting answers on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your programming error is in initilizing `reverse_gifts`: `range(n)` is a *single* object, an iterator.  It is *not* a list of `n` integers.  A simple `print(reverse_gifts)` shows that:

```
[range(0, 4)]
```

Instead, use a list comprehension:

```
reverse_gifts=[i for i in range(n)]
```

Now your program performs as expected.

Comment: Is `[i for i in range(n)]` preferred way or does it have advantages over `list(range(n))`?

Comment: It's not a big deal in this case; the technique is called a "list comprehension", and is quite useful as a programming tool, as are the `list` and `*` operations that Sheldore posted.

Comment: Lolz, it was me who commented :) You answered as if addressing to the OP. I am of course aware of the LC